# How to stop JRE from creating temporary files in JasperReports Server

Tags: java, jasper-reports, temporary-files

My JasperReports Server is creating over 10 temporary files every minute. The file name starts with "virt". According to Jaspersoft, these files are being created by JRE when handling Font. I haven't experienced Tomcat creating so many temporary files before. How can I stop JRE from creating these files.

http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/answers-most-common-questions-regarding-jfxxxxxtmp-temporary-files